# Iframe reload losses correct path to view resource

Tags: javascript, .net, iframe

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ztO4.png)First call to the iframe load content from:

```
/UI/Page/UserControll.aspx
```

And everything works as expected.

After I submit data and I call method:

```
iframe.reload()
```

Code inside the method change url to:

```
/UI/Page/UI/Page/UserControll.aspx
```

And it throws 404 error

The error is inside lib in lines:

```
window.frames[this.iframe.id].location.replace(url);this.beforeIFrameLoad(config);
```

Do you know why the url is replacing without my control?

[First call config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ztO4.png)

[Second call config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDlZ0.png)

Comment: Try the path "./UI/Page/UserControll.aspx" (adding a dot before the first slash)

Comment: Honestly right now in first call config has "~/UI/Page/UserControll.aspx", so I thinks it' s not a problem

Comment: Try accessing it over HTTP with http://?

Comment: The question is why it add extra UI/Pages to url I attached screen with config